# How to find a string including non word character?

Tags: java, regex

How to find a string including non word character?

```
Example input: l l'oreal s.a. l l' ab l
search String: l
output: XX l'oreal s.a. XX l' ab l
Expected: XX l'oreal s.a. XX l' ab X
```

I was trying to find the search string in the input string using the below regex.

```
    String inputStr = "l l'oreal s.a. l l' ab l";
    System.out.println(inputStr);
    String searchStr = "l";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\b"+ searchStr +"\\b)(?=[\\s])");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);

    if ( matcher.find()){
        String rep = matcher.replaceAll("XX");
        System.out.println("REP:" + rep);
    }else{
        System.out.println("no match...");
    }
```

The regex pattern searches for the string where it is followed by a space(\s). But in the above example it doesn't work for the last character since it was not followed by a space.

The main goal was to find string with non word characters like...
private-limited ( when searching for private should return false)
Hello! ( false when searched for Hello)
Couple of patterns which tried but not working...

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<![\\w+])" + searchStr + "(?![\\W+])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=[\\s])(\\b"+ searchStr +"\\b)(?=\\s)");
```

In the above example if I replace searchString = "l'" it doesn't match anything.

Is my approach correct?
What is that I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution, if you can modify the string to search, would be to concatenate it with a space before and afterwards, then simply search for " l "

Comment: Already tried that, but it will not work if the search string is at the starting or at the end.

Comment: Interesting, because I thought my solution would directly counter the beginning and end search.  Why wouldn't this work?

'String inputStr = " " + "l l'oreal s.a. l l' ab l" + " ";
    System.out.println(inputStr);
    String searchStr = " l ";'

Comment: And I apologize for the poor formatting in the comment there

Comment: In your example, since you are adding spaces to your input string it will match. If you take this paragraph is there a space in the beginning of the paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps word boundary followed by whitespace or end of input.

In your case for `l`

```
\b(l)(\s+|$)
```

[Demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/jY1kR7/1)